# Can anyone help me to find the issue in insertion query based on date range in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting date range and multiple ids (chkarray) from checkboxes
ids and date range are getting fine loop is also perfectly executing but my mysql queries are not being executed.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include ('db.php'); 
    $date_start = $_POST['date_start'];
    $date_end = $_POST['date_end'];
    $chkarray = $_POST['chk'];
    $shift = $_POST['shiftTime'];
    if(!empty($date_start)){
    echo "Start date: $date_start"."<br>";
    echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
$i=0;

while ($date_start<=$date_end){
  echo "<br>".$i."<br>".$date_start."<br>";
  foreach ($chkarray as $val) {  
    echo $val."  ";
$new_date = $date_start;
$sql1=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("Select * FROM user_shift_test WHERE userid='$val' ",$conn));
$e_id=$sql1['id'];
$e_name=$sql1['name'];
$e_dayoff=$sql1['dayoff'];
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_new_test (userid,id,name,shift,date_start,date_end,dayoff,updatetime) VALUES ('$val','$e_id','$e_name','$shift','$new_date','$date_end','$e_dayoff',now())");
if($sql1){
echo "Success";
}
else{echo "ERROR!!!!<br>";}
```

**Each time Error line is being print**

```
}$date_start = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date_start)));
$i++;
}
echo "<br>Successfully Inserted";
}//first if closing
else{
echo "Nothing selected";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Comment: `index` is a reserved word and you should wrap inside backticks ``

Comment: Thanks it helped me but still its not getting the name and id from db

Comment: echo your select query on webpage and then copy from there and execute in phpmyadmin on your db.See whether you get any error there ?

Comment: @Mahamadali Select query is not working on `WHERE` i dont understand why its sending null in select and inserting values in insert query fine

Comment: means if you are not adding WHERE clause then all works fine or it is passing $val as null in query ?

Comment: yeah that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine. I changed it to mysqli

```
<?php
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include ('db.php'); 
    $date_start = $_POST['date_start'];
    $date_end = $_POST['date_end'];
    $chkarray = $_POST['chk'];
    $shift = $_POST['shiftTime'];
if(!empty($date_start)){
echo "Start date: $date_start"."<br>";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
$i=0;

while ($date_start<=$date_end){
echo "<br>".$i."<br>".$date_start."<br>";
 foreach ($chkarray as $val) {  
    echo $val."  ";
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$database_username,$database_password,$database_name);
$new_date = $date_start;
$sql1=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"Select * FROM user_shift_test WHERE userid='$val' "));
echo $e_id=$sql1['id'];
echo $e_name=$sql1['name'];
echo $e_dayoff=$sql1['dayoff'];
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users_new_test (userid,id,name,shift,date_start,date_end,dayoff,updatetime) VALUES ('$val','$e_id','$e_name','$shift','$new_date','$date_end','$e_dayoff',now())");
if($sql1){
echo "Success";
}
else{echo "ERROR!!!!<br>";}
```

Now its working fine. Error is gone now

```
}$date_start = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date_start)));
$i++;
}
echo "<br>Successfully Inserted";
}//first if closing
else{
echo "Nothing selected";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```